# Liquibase: onDelete="CASCADE" - deleting parent doesn't delete child, but deleting child deletes parent

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, liquibase

I have two entities (giving You simplified versions):

```
<createTable tableName="wallet_information"
             remarks="A table to contain wallet data">
    <column name="id" type="bigint(20)" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
    </column>
    <column name="user_uuid" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="wallet_name" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="wallet_address" type="varchar(63)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="verification_challenge_id" type="bigint(20)">
        <constraints nullable="true"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

And:

```
<createTable tableName="verification_challenge"
             remarks="A table to contain challenge data">
    <column name="id" type="bigint(20)" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
    </column>
    <column name="challenge_type" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

And finally:

```
   <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="wallet_information" 
        baseColumnNames="verification_challenge_id"
        constraintName="verification_challenge_fk"
        referencedTableName="verification_challenge" 
        referencedColumnNames="id"
        onDelete="CASCADE"/>
```

Then I persist some data in those tables using Hibernate.

Currently I am not deleting any data from those tables from the code perspective, but when I manually delete an entry in `wallet_information`, the referenced entry in `verification_challenge` is not deleted alongside it.

But when I delete an entry in `verification_challenge`, the referenced entry in `wallet_information` is deleted.

I assumed that `onDelete="CASCADE"` will behave quite in opposite way...

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

> **I assumed that onDelete="CASCADE" will behave quite in opposite way...**

Ahh.. not really, [it works](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-foreign-key-constraint.html) as it should be, in your shared code

```
   <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="wallet_information" 
        baseColumnNames="verification_challenge_id"
        constraintName="verification_challenge_fk"
        referencedTableName="verification_challenge" 
        referencedColumnNames="id"
        onDelete="CASCADE"/>
```

Meaning whenever you delete record within `verification_challenge` table all the associated entities that have cascading on delete like `wallet_information` will be deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your foreign key set up backwards from what your business logic expects.

From the Liquibase side, It's just generating SQL like `alter table wallet_information add constraint verification_challenge_fk ... on delete cascade` which tells the database "when you have a delete that would cause this constraint to fail, delete the problem data". So in your case "when you delete a verification_challenge, delete the wallet_information".

So your fix should be to remove the `verification_challenge_id` column from `wallet_information` and add a `wallet_information_id` column to `verification_challenge` instead. Then, the onDelete=cascade logic will match what you are expecting.

Comment: A stupid question, but how should I access the `verification_challenge` from `wallet_information` from the java code perspective? From what I understand - I should remove the `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "verification_challenge_id")
    private VerificationChallenge verificationChallenge;` from the `WalletInformation` object, and add `WalletInformation` to `VerificationChallenge`. So when selecting `WalletInformation` from the database I won't have the `VerificationChallenge` attached. Should I do it with another DB request?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used hibernate so I don't know off hand. If I remember correctly, though, you are able to set up the mapping to be bi-directional, so both objects can be referenced from either side.